# Swift Formatting String to have 2 decimal numbers if it is not a whole number

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string that I would like to be formatted such that when it is not a whole number, it will display up to two decimal places but if it is a whole number, there should be no decimal places.

Is there an easier way to do this in swift or do I have to settle for an if-else?

Comment: please add code what you have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `FloatingPoint` to check if it is a whole number and use a condition to set the `minimumFractionDigits` property of the `NumberFormatter` to 0 in case it is true otherwise set it to 2:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let custom: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return formatter
    }()
}
extension FloatingPoint {
    var isWholeNumber: Bool { isNormal ? self == rounded() : isZero }
    var custom: String {
        Formatter.custom.minimumFractionDigits = isWholeNumber ? 0 : 2
        return Formatter.custom.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
1.0.custom    // "1"
1.5.custom    // "1.50"
1.75.custom   // "1.75"
```

Comment: I have never seen that question and it is already closed. Btw none of them uses the approach I showed here.

Comment: yes your solution might a better than other's so you can answer old questions as a better solution. as old question been searched the most then newer so this would be more helpful :)

Comment: Appreciate the answer, I don't think it's a duplicate since I was actually asking if there's a shorter way of doing it than having to do any calculations for it