# How I can print Double with 2 digit after point and hide if they are zero?

Tags: swift

How I can print Double with 2 digit after point and hide if they are zero?

- 5.12345 -> 5.12
- 5.00000 -> 5
- 5.10000 -> 5.10

Comment: Please try my answer. If it meets  your expectations , remark as accepted. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334494/swift-formatting-string-to-have-2-decimal-numbers-if-it-is-not-a-whole-number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this

```
func format(_ x: Double) -> String {
    if Double(Int(x)) == x {
        return String(Int(x))
    } else {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        guard let s = numberFormatter.string(for: x) else {
            fatalError("Couldn't format number")
        }
        return s
    }
}

format(5.12)  //"5.12"
format(5.0)   //"5"
format(5.10)  //"5.10"
```

Comment: this will create a new number formatter every time you call this method.

Comment: @LeoDabus yes I do remember that from last time

Comment: numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0, right?

Comment: @AleksandrMaybach No it's not. See the question: "*5.10000 -> 5.10*"